# Is there a quicker way to show that a set of vectors is a spanning set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say set $S = \{(2,1,4), (1,-1,1), (3,2,5)\}$ and the vector space V is $R^3$. 
In this case, the number of independent vectors is equal to the dimension of the vector space. I know that one way to show that S is a spanning set for V is by showing that a linear combination of the vectors can equal any vector $(a,b,c)$. My professor told us to set up an augmented matrix and show that the rank of A is equal to the rank of A|b.

I would like to know if there is a less tedious method. If I should stick to this method, I would like to know why.

---

Edit

Let's say $S = \{(2,1,4), (1,-1,1), (3,2,5), (1,4,-2) \}$

How can I prove that a set spans a vector space if the number of independent vectors is larger than the dimension of the vector space? I won't be able to show that the set is a basis, and therefore also a spanning set. Is there a quick proof?

---

Edit 2  (for Future Reference)

The set S cannot have 4 independent vectors because the vectors are in $R^3$. If set S has more than 3 vectors it can still span $R^3$. That can be proven by finding a basis within the set.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to show.  If you want to show that $S$ spans $V$, then you're done as $|S| = 3 = \dim R^3$.  Prove that if $S$ is a linearly indep. set of the same size as the dimension of the space, then the set must span the space.

Comment: What does |S| mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant test is worthwhile. Let $M$ be a matrix whose column vectors are from $S$. The vectors in $S$ form a basis if and only if $det(M) \neq 0$.

I figure I'll edit my answer so nobody has to dig through all the comments (and in light of the edit on the OP). A basis is a maximally independent set. It also spans the space. So if $|S| > dim(V)$, then it is necessary to find a basis to show $S$ spans $V$. There are $\binom{|S|}{dim(V)}$ basis candidates to choose from $S$. The general way to construct a basis is to start with an empty set and add in vectors. If the vector you are examining makes the set linearly dependent, throw it out. The multiples test is one test. If you see $v = kx$, for some $x$ in your set and $k \in \mathbb{F}$, then $v$ and $x$ are linearly dependent. You could also row-reduce to determine linear (in)dependence. Once you can construct a square matrix, you can use the determinant test.

Comment: But the determinant test shows that the vectors from S are independent. I want to show that the set spans V.

Comment: The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is $3$. So if you have three independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, you have a basis.

Comment: Let's say there were 4 independent vectors in S. Can I automatically assume S spans $R^3$?

Comment: Yes, because any three of the vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. A basis is a minimum spanning set.

Comment: Last question. Am I allowed to prove that S spans V by taking any 3 of the 4 vectors in S and showing that determinant is not identically zero?

Comment: You can never have more than three independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Jonas Granholm makes a good point. If any subset of three vectors from $S$ are linearly independent, then you have a basis. You have $4$ possible sets to check. This is an existential quantifier; you only need a single basis.

Comment: That makes a lot sense. Anyway, the only quick way to show that a set spans a space is by showing that the set is a basis for the space. Am I correct?

Comment: You want to find a basis within the set. A basis is a maximally independent set.

Comment: @Tad: No, there is a quick way: just compute the determinant of the set. A computer algebra system can do this in one line of code. If it's nonzero, it's a spanning set. Otherwise, if it's zero, then it's not a spanning set.